# SSRS report refuses to print in landscape

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014-express, ssrs-2014

This is using ReportViewer in a WinForms application.  Teh original app was written back in 2006. The report prints landscape if I go directly from the report server but that doesn't work for my usecase.

I am loosing my mind.  This should be easy and obvious.  There is a landscape setting in the report, there is a legal page size.  The report should print across the page.  But NOOOOOOO.....and I've been working on this for hours.  I have finally gotten it down to something that might trigger someones knowledge and experience.   First here is the report properties setting page for the report:
[image]

I have intentionally set the paper size as custom and the sizes to not exactly legal because I have reports that are really badges and completely non standard and the same code I'm about to show works fine.  Changing this to legal landscape and 14 width 8.5 height makes no difference.  Now here is the code that is run when the print button on the reportviewer is pushed.

```
private void Print(bool showDialog)
{
    if (_streams == null || _streams.Count == 0)
        return;

    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    //printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = _report.Copies;
    //if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    //{
    //    MessageBox.Show("error");
    //    return;
    //}


    //Reports like Registration and Overview Badges have custom page
    //sizes defined in the RDL file, grab that PaperSize and assign 
    //it to the current print document.
    ReportPageSettings settings = reportViewer.ServerReport.GetDefaultPageSettings();
    printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = settings.PaperSize;

    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);

    //printDoc.Print();
    PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
    dlg.Document = printDoc;
    if (showDialog == false || dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        printDoc.Print();
}
```

when this is run and there is a break on PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = settings.PaperSize, the immediate window shows:

```
? settings
{Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportPageSettings}
    IsLandscape: true
    Margins: {[Margins Left=50 Right=50 Top=0 Bottom=0]}
    PaperSize: {[PaperSize  Kind=Custom Height=1350 Width=825]}
```

As you can see the height and width are reversed from what I have entered in report properties.  I have not been able to do anything to fix this.  The result is the report looks like this:
[image]
If i run the same report from the report server directly without involving reportviewer it runs as expected:
[image]

Comment: You need to change the report Properties. Click on the top left hand corner of the report in the layout tab.
(i.e.Right click the corner square) and select properties. Swap the page length and width!
Also change borders here if you want!

Comment: how is that different than what is pictured in the first image in my post? and yes I have tried legal and 14in width 8.5in height to no avail